# Convert Django Filters to RAW SQL Queries

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Hello Everyone Can anyone Help Me ragarding this?
I want to convert a django filter query to raw sql query and below is the example
Django Query

```
Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=self.request.GET.get('product_name'))
```

Is there a online method or some other way that i can convert it to RAW sql Query for my postgresql database or any database.
I dont know that much about database queries
Ill be thankful if someone could help.

Comment: query = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=self.request.GET.get('product_name')).query

Answer (score 0):

You can see SQL that will be run from any Django queryset by converting the `.query` attribute to a string

```
queryset = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=self.request.GET.get('product_name'))
print(str(queryset.query))
```